# Apache won't update html but it's not the usual fix

Tags: html, apache

I'm having a common problem with Apache, but I don't think it has the same common cause, and therefor no common solution.

It started out with an update to my index file (html) not being reflected in the browser. I searched this website and Google high and low, took the advice I found, and checked my own usual suspects as well. I cleared the browser's cache, tried different browsers, browsers that had never visited the website before, and asked people in different cities whom had never even heard of this website to go to the website for me and see what displays - every time the old index file displays, but not the new one.

Here's the weird part: As a last result, I uninstalled Apache, and then went and deleted the Apache directory, re-installed Apache, and when I visited the URL, I STILL saw the old version of the website.

What could cause some one whom had never been to the website before see the old index file after a complete uninstall and then a clean re-install?

Comment: Where are your web pages stored? Why would deleting the Apache directory affect your HTML files in you're in say `/var/www/html/` or something outside of the Apache directory? It sounds like you're not updating the file that's actually being served.

Comment: Do you have a `.htaccess` file in your htdocs or /var/www directory?  If so, it may be changing the Apache directives.

Comment: @j08691 This is a Windows installation, so the html files being served are located in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs`. I deleted the installation directory after deleting contents of the htdocs directory failed to change anything in the hopes that I might also delete some sort of cache file.

Comment: Are you sure?  The file is usually a hidden file.  If not that, then you should check the apache configuration file.  I'm sorry I don't know the windows extension ( I use Ubuntu, and it is usually located at /etc/apache2/httpd.conf); I would assume this is not replaced on the fresh install, since the problem is repeating itself.  Also, to clear the cache, you only need to refresh the browser while holding the shift key.

Comment: Clearing the browser's cache was the first thing I did, and also ruled out since browsers on this computer, other computers, other networks, and browsers on computers on networks that had never visited the site before all show the old version. The cache I was talking about would be a server cache, which Apache has, but is not enabled by default. I'M STYMIED! 

I'm set to see hidden files, and I used the DOS command DIR with the /A H switch to show hidden files, but honestly I don't know how Windows handles the preceding dot in .htaccess

:'-(

Comment: Well I switched to nginx some time ago and it works beautifully, but I still wish I knew what was causing the trouble with Apache.

Answer (score 1):

I do not have an answer to this as of right now, just that I know what worked for me are:

```
  sudo apt-get install apache2 --force-reinstall=true
  init 6  
  sudo systemctl start apache2
```

I had the exact problem trying to test JavaScript in my Apache Raspberry Pi Project and it would never update the html file. The strangest part, sometimes a restart of the Pi would make the changes, and other times it wouldn't.