# Caching issue with Apache; css and html not updating

Tags: apache, .htaccess, caching

I've recently setup a vps on Ubuntu 20.04 to host a single website amongst other non-apache related things. I've been attempting to work on my site but it seems that the files are being cached. For instance, I can still access the webpage and stylesheet even though its been deleted. Thus far I've spent a couple hours searching for a solution to this. I've looked through [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12115096/apache-wont-update-html-but-its-not-the-usual-fix), [this](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2192047) and [this](https://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/). I've also tried the suggestion of one place in adding to my .htaccess as follows:

```
#Initialize mod_rewrite
RewriteEngine On
<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|js|css)$">
  FileETag None
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header unset ETag
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
    Header set Pragma "no-cache"
    Header set Expires "Wed, 12 Jan 1980 05:00:00 GMT"
  </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

After adding that, restarting apache but still with no success. I've found other posts seemingly with the same issue as me which talk about editing 000-default.conf but I lack the technical understanding of apache to be able to make informed choices on editing things like that out of fear of breaking something.

I believe that apache caching is my issue but I could well be wrong. I can't think of what else it would be though. I think this is an issue I've had in the past but I don't remember the solution. Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Adding `?v=1.x.x` to the end of the stylesheet URL fixed the issue. Credit to a Reddit user [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/apache/comments/mkxrjn/disable_caching/)